# PHP Rewrite URL not getting right access

Tags: php, url-rewriting, get

I have switch case php page to detect $_GET function and change between pages.

```
$page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : null;
switch ($page) {
case "advertise":
break;
case "news":
break;
default:
break;
```

I try to access "news" and it available using http://example.com/?p=news. I also create a pagination inside it so it will be available http://example.com/?p=news&page=1

Now I want to change the url become a friendly one http://example.com/news
I created this htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [NC,L]
```

It's work for basic "news" page to access by http://example.com/news. The problem is, I cannot access the pages between its.

http://example.com/news/page=2

It will give me an default page of "news" without giving any pages of that page.

can someone figure out, how to use friendly SEO url with Switch case $_GET and htaccess?

===========================EDIT===================

```
$seourl = $settings['seo_link'];
if($seourl){
    $main_page = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $page = substr(strtolower(preg_replace('([^a-zA-Z0-9-/])', '', $main_page[1])), 0, 20);
    $page_cat = isset($main_page[3]) ? $main_page[3] : null;
    $page_cat_name = isset($main_page[2]) ? $main_page[2] : null;
    $page_val = isset($main_page[5]) ? $main_page[5] : null;
}else{
    $main_page = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if (isset($main_page['query'])){
        parse_str($main_page['query'], $url);
    $pages = array();
    foreach ($url as $key => $value) {
        $pages[] = $url[$key];
    }
    $url_pages = array();
    foreach ($url as $key => $value) {
        $url_pages[] = $key;
    }
    $page = substr(strtolower(preg_replace('([^a-zA-Z0-9-/])', '', $pages['0'])), 0, 20);
    }else{
        $page = '';
    }
    $page_cat = isset($pages[1]) ? $pages[1] : null;
    $page_cat_name = isset($url_pages[1]) ? $url_pages[1] : null;
    $page_val = isset($pages[2]) ? $pages[2] : null;
}

if($seourl){
    function surl($link){
      $url = strtolower($link);
      $patterns = $replacements = array();
      $patterns[0] = '/([?&])p=/i';
      $replacements[0] = '/';
      $patterns[1] = '/[^a-zA-Z01-9]/i';
      $replacements[1] = '/';
      $patterns[2] = '/(-+)/i';
      $replacements[2] = '/';
      $patterns[3] = '/(-$|^-)/i';
      $replacements[3] = '';
      $url = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $url);
      return $url;
    }
}else{
    function surl($link){
            return $link;
    }
}
```

By using this I will be able to turn on and off the SEO url.

if **SEO url is off** (0). I can access http://example.com/?p=news and even it's page http://example.com/?p=news&page=2. Work without any problem.

But if **SEO url is on** (1). I can access https://example.com/news but cannot access it page http://example.com/news/page/2. It will give me result this page always https://example.com/news

Can anyone help me. please

Comment: Where do you expect a parameter `p` to come from here? Your original URL `/news/page=2` did not contain that, and what you are rewriting to also does not add a parameter by that name.

Comment: http://example.com/?p=news&page=1 from here? parameter $_GET['p'] will be "news". How to achieve this?

Comment: So what URL do you actually want to use on the client side for your pagination - `/news/page=2`? Then you will either have to take this apart in PHP, or write a more specific RewriteRule that rewrites this to the index.php with those two separate parameters already.

Comment: Actually I made an options in my database with value 1 or 0, if settings SEO url 1 then use slash, if 0 then use $_GET parameter. Update first post, please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a way to out of this fix.

first we need to add this code inside the function seo url

```
$paginates = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
```

Then your url will work like a charm. Thanks all for helping me out.